# Get values using multiplus buttons inside a foreach asp.net core

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have multiplus buttons in a foreach and, when I click at one, need to submit/send his data- values to an action/method. How can I do this?

```
  <form asp-area="App" id="formMenu">
     @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Atendimento)
     {
             @* I was doing with inputs, but with more than one button, I can't do it anymore
             <input value="@item.IdProduto" name="id" type="hidden" />
             <input value="@item.IdProdutoMeia" name="idMeio" id="idMeio" type="hidden" />
             <input value="@item.Quantidade" name="Qtd" type="hidden" />

             <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" id="btnEdit">
                 Edit
             </button>
             *@

             @* So, I started trying like this *@
             <button class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm" onClick="btnEdit(this)"  data-id="@item.IdProduto" data-idmeio="@item.IdProdutoMeia" data-qtd="@item.Quantidade">
                <i class="fas fa-pen fa-sm"></i>
             </button>
     }
 </form>


 <script type="text/javascript">

       // With just one button, like I sad, it was working fine like this
       $("#btnEdit").click(function () {
            if ($("#idMeio").val() == '') {
                $("#formMenu").attr("action", "@Url.Action("Edit", "Produto")");
            } else {
                $("#formMenu").attr("action", "@Url.Action("EditMeio", "Produto")");
            };
            $("#formMenu").submit();
        });


     // So I have been traying this way, but don't know how to do
     function btnEdit(event) {
            var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
            var idItem = button.attr('data-id')
            var idItemMeio = button.attr('data-idmeio')
            var qtdItem = button.attr('data-qtd')

           ???
    };
    </script>
```

Please help with some idea, code etc

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple buttons and all the buttons are with tag `<button>` then apply click function with button tag and get button id. On the basis of button id, related URL can be set to call Action method.

```
$("button").click(function () {
            alert(this.id);
            var btnId = this.id
        });
```

Comment: To get the ids worked well, the problem is with the submit. Because there are multiplus inputs with the same name/id. So, the values submited are aways the first of the foreach.

Comment: And all the others buttons on the application are know faring the function.

Comment: Put your buttons outside foreach loop

Comment: I can't, each foreach line has your own buttons. That is, each foreach line has a set of buttons and a set of inputs value to be submited.

Comment: It is a list of orders. So, each order have a set of buttons (Edit, Delete...)

Comment: Then you need to use Ajax function to redirect the specific Action method